# Changing a fieldset label on an ui-components form

Tags: magento2.2, uicomponent, fieldsets

I have a form built with ui-components.
And when changing a field, I'm trying to change the label of the fieldset that contains that field.
Here is what I have (the significant part)

THe fieldset definition:

```
             <fieldset name="steps">
                <settings>
                    <label translate="true">Step config</label>
                    <collapsible>true</collapsible>
                </settings>
                <field name="title" formElement="input" component="[Namespace_Module]/js/fieldset-title">
                    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="fit" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                    <settings>
                        <validation>
                            <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                        </validation>
                        <dataType>text</dataType>
                        <label>Title</label>
                        <dataScope>title</dataScope>
                    </settings>
                </field>
            </fieldset>
```

and the `fieldset-title` js file that handles my title field looks like this:

```
define([
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
    'uiRegistry'
], function (Abstract, uiRegistry) {
    'use strict';

    return Abstract.extend({
        onUpdate: function (value) {
            var fieldset = uiRegistry.get({'name': this.parentName});
            fieldset.label(value);
        }
    });
});
```

What I'm saying here is ... "when the value of my input changes, set the same value as fieldset label".

Additional info:
Inside js, fieldset is retrieved properly. I get the fieldset instance I need.
The `value` variable is what I'm expecting it to be.

Other than 
`fieldset.label(value);` I tried `fieldset.label = value;` `fieldset.setLabel(value);`, `fieldset.getLabel(value);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done it in a very ugly way (yep...jquery). If someone has a cleaner method, please share.

my custom component looks like this now.

```
define([
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
    'jquery'
], function (Text, $) {
    'use strict';

    return Text.extend({
        onUpdate: function (value) {
            $('#' + this.uid).closest('.fieldset-wrapper').find('.fieldset-wrapper-title span:first').html(value);
            return this._super();
        }
    });
});
```

Not very proud of if, but it works with a standalone fieldset.
But if this fieldset is part of a record of a dynamic-records component, the title is reset once a new record is added or deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the code a bit in a clean and better manner. It may be useful to others :)

```
define([
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
    'jquery'
], function (Text, $) {
    'use strict';

    return Text.extend({
        onUpdate: function (value) {
            $("label[for=" + this.uid + "]").text(value);
            return this._super();
        }
    });
});
```